# Yield Syntax apparent inconsistency in Scala for Expresisons?

Tags: scala

I am trying to learn scala and I am trying to understand why the following is legal:

```
for (idx <- 1 to 10) yield idx
```

but the following is not legal.

```
for (idx <- 1 to 10) { yield idx }
```

They seem syntactically the same. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: BTW, pages 124-125 of Odersky's "Programming in Scala" covers this.  I would suggest it highly.  In it it says "The yield goes before the entire body" where the synax is like `for clauses yield body`.

Comment: @sberry, since you mention the book, here is the online link from the 1st edition: http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/builtin-control-structures.html#lst:mid-stream-assignment

Answer (score 9):

Because that's the way the parser works, here is the part from [Scala specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf):

```
Expr1 ::= ‘for’ (‘(’ Enumerators ‘)’ | ‘{’ Enumerators ‘}’)
  {nl} [‘yield’] Expr
```

It says we can have for with one or many so named enumerators, `{nl}` says we can nest multiple `for`s like

```
for(...)
  for(...) 
    ...
```

We can add optional `yield` keyword followed by expression, but there is no place for braces. Expression (body) on it's own can be `(idx)`, `{idx}`, just `idx` or something else so this is legal:

```
for (idx <- 1 to 10) yield { idx }
```

Answer (score 1):

This comes down to how the for-expression is de-sugared (and the parser rules associated with it).

In the first case, the compiler will de-sugar the comprehension to be the following:

```
(1 to 10).map(idx => idx)
```

The second case is a shorthand that allows people to use for-loops (which is potentially troublesome). The second form of the `for` is essentially performing a `foreach` where the result is always `Unit` and therefore `yield` is not possible because the return type is already defined.

Answer (score 1):

`yield` It seems it can be replaced with `map`.
Therefore making this possible

```
for (idx <- 1 to 10) yield {val square = idx * idx; square}
```

You can find more on this from [scala-yield-syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9796939/scala-yield-syntax) and alot more detail here [can-someone-explain-scalas-yield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052476/can-someone-explain-scalas-yield)